# How can I use the built in WooCommerce geolocation?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation

I know that WooCommerce has a built in GeoLocation function, I was wondering how can I use it on other sections of the site, for example, display certain elements based on the location. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WC_Geolocation class for this: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Geolocation.html

Either you build a custom theme or child-theme using that functionality or you build your own shortcodes for the current theme: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API